# Excel calculated field doesn't return correct value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've got a problem with calculated fields in Excel. It simply returns the wrong value and I can't seem to get it correct. I've tried "Students*Cost per student" and it returns correctly in the "Program" row, but not on the "School" row nor the Total sum.

For example School3 should return 50+80+80+50 = 260.

Image:

[image]

Data: [https://pastebin.com/fBLWv2EU]

Comment: It returns correct value. For total row field calculates ```Total students``` * ```Total cost``` i.e. ```4*180=720```. This behavior cannot be changed

Comment: you can do the calculations in the data set by adding another column and reference it instead of doing the calc in the pivot table.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner! Thats a simple solution that works... can't believe I didnt think of that:)